# How do i retain the results of an onclick function

Tags: javascript, onclick, innerhtml

I am writing javascript function for a grid rotator that should rotate the buttons when one button is clicked.

I am developing a grid rotator which consists of a 3x3 grid form with buttons labeled 1-9. my code should rotate the outer buttons when 5 is clicked. When i click the button, they rotate but immediately return to their initial state. please help me ensure that the result of the rotation stays. This is my second day coding JS.

```js
Button_5.onclick = function() {
  var viarableNum = Button_1.innerHTML;
  Button_1.innerHTML = Button_4.innerHTML;
  Button_4.innerHTML = Button_7.innerHTML;
  Button_7.innerHTML = Button_8.innerHTML;
  Button_8.innerHTML = Button_9.innerHTML;
  Button_9.innerHTML = Button_6.innerHTML;
  Button_6.innerHTML = Button_3.innerHTML;
  Button_3.innerHTML = Button_2.innerHTML;
  Button_2.innerHTML = viarableNum;
}
```

```css
form {
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 4px;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  background-color: rgb(182, 95, 95);
  padding: 4px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-left: 40%;
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.button {
  background-color: rgba(212, 210, 68, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 4px;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
  <title>Rotate</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <button id="Button_1" class="button">1</button>
    <button id="Button_2" class="button">2</button>
    <button id="Button_3" class="button">3</button>
    <button id="Button_4" class="button">4</button>
    <button id="Button_5" class="button">5</button>
    <button id="Button_6" class="button">6</button>
    <button id="Button_7" class="button">7</button>
    <button id="Button_8" class="button">8</button>
    <button id="Button_9" class="button">9</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My expected output should maintain the result of the onclick function when 5 is clicked. it works with a div tag but not with the form. please help.  Thanks in advance

Comment: Not really a duplicate - that answer provides a solution to this issue, but the OP was not aware that it was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Clicking a button inside a form does by default submit the form, reloading the current page. Give the button the type "button" so that it does not trigger form submission.

```
<form>
<button type="button" id="Button_1" class="button">1</button>
<button type="button" id="Button_2" class="button">2</button>
<button type="button" id="Button_3" class="button">3</button>
<button type="button" id="Button_4" class="button">4</button>
<button type="button" id="Button_5" class="button">5</button>
<button type="button" id="Button_6" class="button">6</button>
<button type="button" id="Button_7" class="button">7</button>
<button type="button" id="Button_8" class="button">8</button>
<button type="button" id="Button_9" class="button">9</button>
</form>
```

Or remove the `<form>` tags.

Comment: returning false and putting type "button" both worked. thanks guys, you are the best

Comment: You don't need to return false for type "button"

Answer (score -1):

Put `return false` as the last part of your function - that will stop the 'natural' button/submit action from completing.